# Facebook graph API unknown http error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am attempting to use the Facebook JS sdk to retrieve my friends list via FB.api("/me/friends") , but I keep getting the following error: {"type":"http","message":"unknown error"}

When I view the request in Chrome debugger tools it shows the request as failed, but copying the url and going to it in a new window pulls down my friends list data as expected.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was caused by the Avast security plugin blocking social networks.

Comment: Ghostery would cause that too. Disable it if you are developing a fb app (duh!)

Comment: Kaspersky Internet Security also caused the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and it seems that Facebook doesn't like if you put the protocol on the app domain and site url fields inside app settings. I had https://blabla.... Removing the protocol solved the error for me.